# Laravel Sentinel setModel accessing the wrong table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

I am attempting to use multiple tables for my authentication based on a subdomain. Therefore, I am attempting to use Sentinel's `setModel` function during runtime to set the model instance.

So in my routes file I have some simple logic:

```
if (Request::getHost() == $url) {
    Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel('App\Client');
} else {
    Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel('App\User');
}
```

The logic being one URL uses one model and the other uses the other model. Now, when I am attempting to load the `App\Client` by doing a `dd(Sentinel::getUserRepository());` I get a return such as:

```
IlluminateUserRepository {#113 ▼
  #hasher: NativeHasher {#114}
  #model: "App\Client"
  #dispatcher: Dispatcher {#23 ▶}
  #dispatcherStatus: true
}
```

This is great, however, when I call `Sentinel::getUser();`, I am left with the following output:

```
EloquentUser {#230 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #hidden: array:1 [▶]
  #persistableKey: "user_id"
  #persistableRelationship: "persistences"
  #loginNames: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▶]
  #original: array:12 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #permissionsInstance: null
}
```

This is referring to the `App\User` model rather than my `App\Client` model.

I don't understand why, but I can't seem to get functions of Sentinel to look at the model I am trying to reference.

Here is my Client model as a point of reference.

```
namespace App;

class Client extends \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser
{
    /**
     * The fields for sentinel to authenticate (login)
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loginNames = ['email'];

    /**
    * The table associated with model.
    *
    * @var String
    */
    protected $table = 'clients';

    /**
    * Used for mass assignment fields.
    *
    * @var Array
    */
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', 'permissions', 'last_login', 'first_name', 'last_name'];
}
```

I have used [this guide](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/wiki/Extending-Sentinel) from the Github Wiki, however as you can see Im not achieving what I am trying to do.

How can I use this approach of setting the model during runtime and use the correct model with all of sentinels commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who encounters the same issue, i flagged this as an issue in the [cartalyst/sentinel](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel) repository and some feedback was provided.

The solution is to not only set the user repository but also define the model on the persistence repository:

```
Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setUsersModel('App\Client');
Sentinel::getPersistenceRepository()->setUsersModel('App\Client');
```

Through this methods such as `Sentinel::getUser()` will access the model specified above.

Please see the full response here: https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/issues/367